# form in thead element differs from source and DOM

Tags: forms, jsp, dom, spring-mvc

I have a spring-mvc jsp table with a few input elements in the thead to be able to do some filtering. The thead does have a form as child first element.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <form:form action="." modelAttribute="accountWrapper.theAccount">
      <tr><td class="columhead" id="firstname"><div class="disp">first name</div>
            <div class="filter"><form:input path="firstName"/></div></td>
          <td class="columnhead" id="lastname"><div class="disp">last name</div>
            <div class="filter"><form:input path="lastName"/></div></td>
          <td>email</td></tr>
    </form:form>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

When checking the source I see:

```
<thead>
  <form id="accountWrapper.theAccount" action="." method="post">
     <tr><td class="columhead" id="firstname"><div class="disp">first name</div>
           <div class="filter"><input id="theAccount.firstName" name="theAccount.firstName" type="text" value="search"/></div></td>
         <td class="columnhead" id="lastname"><div class="disp">last name</div>
       <div class="filter"><input id="theAccount.lastName" name="theAccount.lastName" type="text" value="search"/></div></td>
         <td>email</td></tr>
  </form>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

As I'm expecting it should be.

But when I'm checking the javascript DOM, the form element is an empty element directly under <thead>, the <input> elements are outside the form. And form submission goes wrong.

```
<thead>
  <form id="accountWrapper.theAccount" action="." method="post"></form>
     <tr><td class="columhead" id="firstname"><div class="disp">first name</div>
           <div class="filter"><input id="theAccount.firstName" name="theAccount.firstName" type="text" value="search"/></div></td>
         <td class="columnhead" id="lastname"><div class="disp">last name</div>
       <div class="filter"><input id="theAccount.lastName" name="theAccount.lastName" type="text" value="search"/></div></td>
         <td>email</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a `<form>` element inside a `<thead>` element. This rule applies to all `<table>` sub elements except `<th>` and `<td>`. For whatever reason, Spring serializes renders the HTML with the `<form>` immediately closed.

Wrap your whole table with the `<form>`.

Comment: I just found this out, and came back to 'remove' my question.